# Animating only part of a UIView drawn context?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, drawing

I am drawing some text and images to a view in the "DrawRect" method.
I wish to understand :

1. does my drawings are separated objects?
2. i know how to animate UIViews but how do i reach one of them so i can animate his properties ?

thanks

shani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O.k

if any one wants to know the answer. you can not animate drawn text or objects unless you draw it to CALayer.